# Get an array of values from a key inside a dict object that it is also a dict

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to transform the `response` object:

```
[
    {
        'var0055':53,
        'var0048': 'Adolf'
    }
    {
        'var0055':16,
        'var0048': 'Julia'
    }
]
```

into `data_var0055`:

```
[53,16]
```

I have tried:

```
data_var0055 = []
i = 0

for item in response:
      data_var055[i] = item['var055']
      i += 1
```

but it is not returning the array `[53,16]`.

Comment: `data_var0055 = [item['var0055'] for item in data]` (where data is the list of dicts)

Comment: key in response is var0055, in the for loop its var055

Comment: Why is this tagged with "embedded"? From the tag wiki: *"Embedded refers to embedded systems, which involves areas such as microcontroller/DSP firmware programming, real-time systems, electronic interfaces, hardware drivers, serial bus communication etc."*

Comment: Hi @Tulio you were using the incorrect key name, please check my answer below, and consider marking it as accepted if it did :)

Answer (score 3):

Some fixes for your code

- You are getting the value for key `var055`, but you want the value for key `var0055` instead
- You don't need to use an index for appending to the list `data_var055`, you can use `list.append` instead

So the code will change to

```
data_var0055 = []

#Iterate over the response and append value for key var0055
for item in response:
      data_var0055.append(item['var0055'])
```

Or you can simplify it in a list comprehension like so:

```
res = [item['var0055'] for item in response]
```

Output will be

```
[53, 16]
```